# UIBezierPath: animate and move transparent circle

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uibezierpath

im trying to create an overlay with transparent hole inside.
When the overlay appear the circle should bounce a little bit then move to bottom of the view.

i create the circle and tried to add the animation and the movement but nothing happen, the circle doesn't move.

here my code:

```
let overlay = UIView(frame: (self.view?.bounds)!)
let radius: CGFloat = 60.0
let circleFrame = CGRect(x: (self.view?.bounds.size.width)!/2, y: (self.view?.bounds.size.height)!/2, width: radius, height: radius)
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.view?.bounds.size.width)!, height: (self.view?.bounds.size.height)!), cornerRadius: 0)
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: circleFrame, cornerRadius: radius)
path.append(circlePath)
path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
fillLayer.path = path.cgPath
fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
fillLayer.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7).cgColor
overlay.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
self.view?.addSubview(overlay)
circlePath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50))
circlePath.stroke()
```

could anyone help on this? thanks.

Comment: Why are you translating the path 10000 points?

Comment: comment edited.

Comment: How are you animating the circle?

Comment: Can I suggest a `guard let view = view else { return }` at the top? Those `!`s make my eyes hurt.

Comment: this is taken from a playground, im prototyping.